# Mixing client-side authentication with server-side authentication

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm struggling to combine client-side authentication with server-side authentication and I appreciate help from the community. My app is simple and all users are on Facebook so I would like to use FB widgets both for login/auth and registration.

After page is loaded I check FB.getLoginStatus and show the fb:login-button if the user is not logged in.Then the user press the login-button and I receive the auth.login event. It's from here I'm a bit uncertain on the next action and I wonder if I'm missing a point.

I try to redirect the user to the server and I was hoping I could use the php-sdk there to check if the user is logged in without any fuzz, but when I do $facebook->api('/me') I get no response.

So how should I pass authorization information to the server in a secure way (my app doesn't use https) so that I can ensure that the user is authentication and authorized on the server side as well when I use the fb-login-button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

does the following example from facebook work for you
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

it is combining javascript with php SDK and there is some additional info you should check

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. That was a very good pointer. When I set oauth true and went looking for that cookie I got it working at once. Better I start to read that blog ;)

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there an updated one?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Client Side Validation you can provide a better user experience by responding quickly at the browser level. When you perform a Client Side Validation, all the user inputs are validated in the user's browser itself. Client Side validation does not require a round trip to the server, so the network traffic which will help your server perform better. This type of validation is done on the browser side using script languages such as JavaScript, VBScript or HTML5 attributes.

   For example, if the user enters an invalid email format, you can show an error message immediately before the user moves to the next field, so the user can correct every field before they submit the form.

   Mostly the Client Side Validation depends on the JavaScript Language, so if users turn JavaScript off, it can easily bypass and submit dangerous input to the server. So the Client Side Validation can not protect your application from malicious attacks on your server resources and databases.

   As both the validation methods have their own significances, it is recommended that the Server side validation is more SECURE!
2. In the Server Side Validation, the input submitted by the user is being sent to the server and validated using one of server side scripting languages such as Node.js. After the validation process on the Server Side, the feedback is sent back to the client by a new dynamically generated web page. It is better to validate user input on Server Side because you can protect against the malicious users, who can easily bypass your Client Side scripting language and submit dangerous input to the server.